# symbolizations in FOL

Tags: logic

I am doing a question of symbolizations in FOL
The problem is ：If Jupiter has a moon, it has a moon with an atmosphere.
Keys are:

- M(x) x is a moon.
- O(x, y)  x orbits y.
- j    Jupiter
- T(x) x has an atmosphere.

I wrote: Ax((M(x)/\O(x,j))->(M(x)/\T(x)/\O(x,j)))

Ax here stands for "for all x", and jupiter has a moon means there is a moon orbiting jupiter

I cannot figure out what I did wrong please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you've written, translated back into natural language, is:

> "For every $x$, if $x$ is a moon orbiting Jupiter then $x$ is a moon orbiting Jupiter with atmosphere."

There is a big problem with this, however: **what if Jupiter has *two* (or more) moons**?

The sentence you're trying to translate merely says that if Jupiter has a moon, then Jupiter has a moon with atmosphere; it does *not* say that all of Jupiter's moons (if it has any) have atmosphere.

Basically, the two clauses "has a moon" and "has a moon with atmosphere" are a bit more independent than you're treating them here. One correct implementation is the following:

> Try $$[\exists x(M(x)\wedge O(x,j))]\implies [\exists y(M(y)\wedge O(y,j)\wedge T(y))].$$ Using different variables here isn't necessary, but it does make things clearer to read.

Comment: You type faster than I do.  :-)

Comment: Thank you so much